# Accidentally sprayed water on desktop computer monitor

Tags: display, water-damage

I was drinking water while watching something and something funny happened and I spit water all over my monitor, which is one used for desktops. "Nothing" happened instantly but I quickly dried it with a towel and then I used paper towel to make sure it was (seemingly) dry. I used my fingernail with the paper towel to see if anything got into the casing at the bottom. It was a bit wet but now it seems dry (or at least the paper isn't wet anymore)

It turns on and off and it seems okay. I've done it a few times and nothing seems wrong, at least in this first 1/2 hour.

I know nothing will ease my paranoia, but am I okay? Or should I start saving up for a new monitor or repairs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once you have dried the monitor with a soft cloth, it will be quite safe. But you should cut the power before you are wiping monitor for safety, unless it could short-circuit. And obviously don't panic at this situation.

Comment: I agree that the user is likely OK - but this is because the water went onto the surface of the monitor which is a layer of protection (glass and plastic are fairly waterproof.  That said, I'm not convinced your your logic is fully correct - I put to you that - water touching contacts can start a corrosion process that wiping won't necessarily remove.  Also, the logic behind removing power is to stop the chemical processes which compound the corrosion.